# What does ARES stand for in Firefall?

Tags: firefall

In Firefall, the quest dialog always refers to you as an ARES (A.R.E.S.?) pilot/team. What does ARES stand for (or is short for)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARES is short for Assault Reconnaissance Extraction Specialist.

Source: [Josh Willcox, Community Manager for Firefall](https://twitter.com/JBWillcox/status/497628784292397057)

Comment: Do you have a source that you could link to?

Comment: @AlbertBori If you insist..